# Excel and Word Created using DynamicReports not showing data properly

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

Using DynamicReports am generating reports in HTML format and have given option to Download it in PDF,WORD and EXCEL format. In HTML format the report is showing fine. But when it comes to PDF,EXCEL and WORD there is an issue. The issue is that in Column Report the data is not fully showing in the cell, not for every cell, cell in which the data is more. 
[image]

The above image is from the HTML which is working fine and showing full data .
[image]

This image is from excel in which you can see 10 is not visible in the 3rd column. The same issue exist in PDF and word also. How do i resolve this issue?

NB:- The same issue was there in PDF also. but i solved it using seeting the `setForceLineBreakPolicy` as true

```
JasperPdfExporterBuilder pdfExporter = export.pdfExporter(file).setSizePageToContent(true).setForceLineBreakPolicy(true);
        report.toPdf(pdfExporter);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392985/xlsx-jasper-report-creating-successfully-but-cell-border-not-visible can you please check this and gave a solution

Answer (score 1):

in order to properly export to Excel, you should prepare your reports following some of the **guidelines wrote down here**: [Making HTML, XLS or CSV friendly reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/making-html-xls-or-csv-friendly-reports)

It's possible that some of the elements composing your report are a bit **overlapping or not properly aligned**.

Thanks...! Hope Working :)